# R dataframe column multiplication with sapply

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to multiply columns in R data.frame. I want to do this based on certain patterns in the column names. This is very elementary task, but I struggle to make it work with sapply() or some related function. This is what I've tried thus far.

```
df <- data.frame("pA" = sample(1:100), "pB" = sample(1:100), "qA" = sample(1:100), "qB" = sample(1:100))
cols <- c("A","B") 

multip <- function(df,col){
    dfp <- df[which(names(df) %in% paste0("p",col))]
    dfq <- df[which(names(df) %in% paste0("q",col))]
    dfv <- dfp*dfq
    setNames(dfv, paste0("v",col))
}

sapply(df, function(x) multip(x,cols))
```

I can make it work if I take it apart and forget the function and sapply parts but that would complicate my work. Is there some solution that would make this work?

Comment: By using `df` on `sapply`/lapply` you are getting only a single column per list element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `multip` directly on 'df'

```
multip(df, cols)
```

Or without using `multip`

```
Map('*', df[grep('p', names(df))], df[grep('q', names(df))])
```

The problem with `sapply/lapply` call is that we get access to only a single column for each list element and that is not the arguments based on the function `multip`